# Confidence interval and p value from prop.test() in R contradict each other

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, z-test

I am running the following simple Z test for proportions in R:

```
prop.test(x = c(10, 20), n = c(100, 500))
```

The results are as follows:

```
2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(10, 20) out of c(100, 500)
X-squared = 5.1158, df = 1, p-value = 0.02371
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.007256322  0.127256322
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.10   0.04
```

How is it possible for the p value of the Z test to be below 0.05, but for the 95% confidence interval to straddle zero? I've found [this question on the behaviour of the prop.test function itself](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183225/confidence-interval-from-rs-prop-test-differs-from-hand-calculation-and-resul) and [this one on the alternative ways of constructing the CI](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436812/exceptions-to-the-rule-if-the-95-ci-does-not-contain-0-then-the-effect-is-sig) but I don't think either explains what's going on in this case.

The top answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302928/disagreement-between-p-values-and-confidence-intervals) suggests I'm right in thinking this output should be impossible!

Answer (score 3):

I think one difficulty may be in the normal (or chi-squared) approximation for relatively small sample sizes. Also, the 'test' part of the output uses the null hypothesis $p_1 = p_2$ to get a pooled estimate for the standard error, whereas the '95% CI' does not assume $p_1 = p_2.$

Fisher's exact test fails to reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level.

```
TAB = rbind(c(10,20), c(90,80))
TAB
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   20
[2,]   90   80

fisher.test(TAB)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TAB
p-value = 0.07343
alternative hypothesis: 
 true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1754757 1.0691978
 sample estimates:
 odds ratio 
  0.4462223
```

Also, `prop.test` in R is roughly equivalent to using a
chi-squared test on the $2\times 2$ table. With Yates'
continuity correction, this procedure does not reject.

```
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TAB
X-squared = 3.1765, df = 1, p-value = 0.07471
```